# Stream content immediately on Nodejs Express

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a Node.js Express server. As soon as I receive a response from getQueryResponse, I want to stream each content to the frontend. For example, if the response is "Hello, how are you?", I want to stream each word as and when it appears. For instance, "H", "e", "l", etc.

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

getResponse() calls another server, sending a streaming response to the Node.js (this) server. When I checked, the other server sends a response to the Node.js server as soon as it receives the data.

However, the Node.js server is currently waiting to receive the entire data or at least a few letters before sending it out as a response.

As a result, it sends "hell" together, then "o" or something similar. But if I can make it send "h" as soon as it receives it, I can improve the speed of the product.

```
     const response = await getResponse()

  response.body.on('data', (chunk) => {
      console.log(chunk.toString());
      res.write(chunk.toString());
    });

    response.body.on('end', () => {
      console.log('Streaming text finished.');
      res.end();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
    res.status(500).end();
  }
```

Console.log (response) looks like this

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  timeout: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 5,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    url: 'http://452323/1212q=hey',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: Headers { [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] },
    counter: 0
 }
```

console.log(chunk.toString());

```
h
e
l
l
o
```

Comment: What is `getResponse`?  Seems like you might actually want to make a request in such a way that you get a _stream_ for the body of the response so that you can _pipe_ the `response.body` to the `res` of your endpoint.  Something like:  `response.body.pipe(res)`

Comment: @Wyck Yes response from getResponse is coming in a streamable way. I have edited question above

Comment: _chunk to string_ will fail if the data happens to arrive in such a way that multi-byte utf-8 encoded character is split.  If you're only expecting ASCII, then you'll be fine. Also, don't be concerned that bytes arrive in chunks like `hell` then `o`, that's just the _Nagle algorithm_ at work. If the planes at the airport left as soon as the first passenger showed up, there'd be a lot of large aircraft with a single passenger on them flying around the skies wasting fuel. The network has similar properties in terms of packets.  I don't suggest fighting it. You could switch to a WebSocket though.